# Java File[] or List<File> or something else?

Tags: java, arrays, list

```
public boolean importData(TransferSupport ts) {
  try {
    String dir = ts.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor).toString();
    dir = dir.substring(1, dir.length()- 1);
    System.out.println(dir);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
    //parsing directory names and converting them into file array
    int lastComma = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i < dir.length(); i++) {
        //System.out.println(dir.substring(i-2,i));
        if(dir.substring(i-2,i).equals(", ")) {
            File file = new File(dir.substring(lastComma,i-2));
            double num = file.length();
            System.out.println(df.format((num/1024)/1024)+"MB");
            lastComma = i; 
        }

    }
}
```

I am implementing a method which takes in list of files by parsing through directory paths. String dir will be contain a directory of files. It will depends on how many files user drag and drop onto the program. Since I am storing info of files into table format, I have to store them into array format or some other data structure. Is there any advise?

most important question is, should I implement it by using File[] array? or List?  I know that implementing it using File[] array will get me to count the number of files user drags and drops.

Comment: Use a List (or a Set). In general, I’d suggest you use an implementation of `Collection` unless you have a specific, good reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

A `List` is more flexible in general.  However, in this case you can replace that messy string splitting code with this:

```
 String[] files = dir.split(", ");
```

which also deals with one of the reasons for using a `List`.  And if you wanted to use a `List` anyway:

```
 List<String> files = Arrays.asList(dir.split(", "));
```

Note that this is a `List<String>` rather than a `List<File>`, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

List is more flexible, array is more constrained. If you have no specific reason to do otherwise, List is the go-first option.